# syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in Stripe form using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error, railscasts

I'm following Ryan Bates' RailsCast #288 "Billing with Stripe" and when I modify my form to include the credit card info I get the following error:

```
compile error
/Programs/domainster/app/views/domains/_form.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected ':',    expecting ')'
...d_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil );@output_buffer.safe_con...
```

I checked my syntax against the RailsCast and the code is identical. I even updated my GemFile to make sure I have the latest Rails running.

Here's my form:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :cvv, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :cvv, nil, name: nil %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %><br />
    <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
    <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Generate"%>
  </div>
```

I followed the RailsCast step-by-step and I have no idea why I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: what does ruby -v give you from the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Ryan is using a Ruby 1.9.2 syntax for hashes

```
 <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
```

would need to be written as

> <%= select_year nil, {:start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year =>
>   Date.today.year+15}, {:name => nil, :id => "card_year"} %>

for running on 1.8.7. Check the other lines to see if there are others that need fixing.

Comment: I just switched to Ruby 1.9.2 using RVM and ran bundle install and I still get the same error. I then changed the syntax to what you suggested and it worked. Any idea why it still gave me the error even after updating to 1.9.2? And by the way, thank you.

Comment: very strange - Ryan was definitely using the new syntax that 1.9.2 introduced. Also these days I'd definitely suggest using 1.9.2 as your default ruby over Ruby 1.8.7.